# SQL "Table_Name.Column_name" VS "Column_name" performance & syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to SQL and am currently working through a "teach yourself SQL book"

It was mentioned in the book that sometimes you NEED to specify table name with column name (immediately after SELECT line) to get your desired result.  It was also mentioned that it is often good practice to do this regardless.  Here is a specific example:

```
SELECT vend_name, prod_name, prod_price
FROM Vendors, Products
WHERE Vendors.vend_id = Products.vend_id;

SELECT Vendors.vend_name, Products.prod_name, Products.prod_price
FROM Vendors, Products
WHERE Vendors.vend_id = Products.vend_id;
```

Both code blocks achieve the same result.  My question is whether there is a performance difference, and if the full names are better practice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, learn proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Second, learn to use table aliases.  These should be abbreviations for the table.  Table aliases make queries easier to write and to read.

Third, always use qualified column names.  Using the column name has no effect on performance.  Oh, perhaps you'll make an exception if you have only one table or something like that.  But, including the table alias is a very good idea, a best practice.  Why?

- You or someone else may look at the query in the future and not want to figure out which names come from which tables.
- You or someone else may add a new column to one of the tables that matches a column in the other.  And, the query mysteriously stops working.
- You or someone else may say "what a great query, but I need to add another table".  The other table has naming conflicts, just introducing more work.

So, I would write the query as:

```
SELECT v.vend_name, p.prod_name, p.prod_price
FROM Vendors v JOIN
     Products p
     ON v.vend_id = p.vend_id;
```

Or, if you like:

```
SELECT v.vend_name, p.prod_name, p.prod_price
FROM Vendors v JOIN
     Products p
     USING (vend_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm assuming there is not a performance difference then? or insignificant? (when using fully qualified column names)

Comment: @TonyDepace . . . No performance difference.  Either version might be nano-seconds faster or slower during the compile phase, but it is hard to tell which would be.

Answer (score 1):

Below format is helpful if you have multiple tables with same column names,in order to reduce the confusions

```
Vendors.vend_name
```

Let me be **simple and short** :

> There wont be any **performance** issues but it is a **good practice**
>   to follow

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I doubt there would be any performance difference. However even if there was It would not be worth it in the long run.

The table.column is good practice as it makes your sql easier to read. This may not seam like a big deal when your learning but you will most likely come across SQL statements that are huge and when you do you will be glad of this practice.

I would recommend you look at the AS keyword. This will allow you to assign an Alias to a table to again make the statement easier to understand.

```
SELECT p.id, v.name
FROM products AS p
JOIN venders as V
ON p.id = v.ProductId
```

This allows you to keep the `SELECT` section of your SQL Statement as short as possible and avoid repeating product. product.  etc for every field you want to show.